# Retyped for Kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, bridge.net

Just started with Bridge.NET, LOVING IT!!

We use the Kendo UI controls in our application. I'm working on a proof of concept using Bridge.NET. I have the following JavaScript straight from Telerik:

```
function onChange(e) {
   var rows = e.sender.select();
   rows.each(function(e) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
      console.log(dataItem); 
   })
};
```

In my C#, the call to e.sender.select() results in a kendo_ui.Jquery interface. I don't seem to be able to treat it like a selector though. Assuming that it really is one, I try wrapping that in a new jQuery2.jQuery(). I can iterate over it then of course, but the call to grid.dataItem(e) tells me my Html5Element is not compatible with any of the calling signatures -- Retyped.dom.Element.Interface, Retyped.kendo_ui.Jquery, or string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The typings provided for Kendo might require some enhancements. We'll to try to figure out a few suggestions and pass them on to the Kendo team.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this thread was continued on the Bridge.NET forums.

https://forums.bridge.net/forum/community/retyped/4901-retyped-for-kendo